# FULL OUTER JOIN duplicating rows using COALESCE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, join

It was a long day, perhaps this is a simple question but i'm stuck anyway.

Basically i have two similar tables `Sales` and `Forecasts`. I'm trying to create a view which selects rows from both tables and picks whatever is there for a given model+month+country. If both tables contain data, `Sales` has priority which means that `Forecast` rows should be omitted.

To simplify the query i'm using CTE's. Actually the schema of both tables is different and many tables are joined, also `Forecasts` contains history rows where only the last should be shown.

I have created a simplified schema and data to show you what i'm trying to do:

```
WITH Sales AS
(
    SELECT 
        ID, Model, Month, Country,
        Amount              = Count,
        [Forecast / Sales]  = 'Sales'
    FROM dbo.Sales
)
, Forecasts AS
(
    SELECT 
        ID, Model, Month, Country,
        Amount              = Count,
        [Forecast / Sales]  = 'Forecast'
    FROM dbo.Forecast
)
SELECT  ID = COALESCE(s.ID, fc.ID), 
        Model = COALESCE(s.Model, fc.Model), 
        Month = COALESCE(s.Month, fc.Month),
        Country = COALESCE(s.Country, fc.Country),
        Amount = COALESCE(s.Amount, fc.Amount),
        [Forecast / Sales] = COALESCE(s.[Forecast / Sales], fc.[Forecast / Sales])
FROM Sales s
FULL OUTER  JOIN Forecasts fc 
    ON s.Model = fc.Model
        AND s.Month = fc.Month
        AND s.Country = fc.Country
ORDER BY ID,Month,Country,Model
```

Here's a sql-fiddle with sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9081b/9/2

Result:

```
ID  MODEL   MONTH   COUNTRY AMOUNT  FORECAST / SALES
1   ABC December, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 Germany 777 Sales
2   ABC January, 01 2014 00:00:00+0000  Germany 999 Sales
3   ABC February, 01 2014 00:00:00+0000 Germany 900 Sales
3   ABC February, 01 2014 00:00:00+0000 Germany 900 Sales
4   ABC January, 01 2014 00:00:00+0000  UK  600 Forecast
4   ABC February, 01 2014 00:00:00+0000 UK  444 Sales
5   ABC March, 01 2014 00:00:00+0000    UK  500 Forecast
```

This query returns duplicates according to the `ID` and the source (last column).

```
3   ABC February, 01 2014 00:00:00+0000 Germany 900 Sales
3   ABC February, 01 2014 00:00:00+0000 Germany 900 Sales
```

Apparently the `Sales` rows are being duplicated by multiple `Forecast`-rows for that model+month+country combination. How do i get only `Sales` rows if `Sales`+`Forecast` rows are available without duplicates and `Forecast` rows if there are no `Sales` rows?

Comment: So, if for a "model+month+country" combo, there are 3 rows in Sales but 5 rows in Forecasts, you want the 3 rows only from Sales?

Comment: the issue is that in the `Forecast` table there are 2 rows with the same `model, month, country`, rows ID 2 and 3. 
Both of them join with the ID 3 row in the `Sales` table, hence the duplicate with ID = 3 in the results

Comment: @ypercube: yes, Sales has priority. Forecast is irrelevant if there is already sales-data.

Comment: @Lamak: Good catch. But even if i've created the sample data manually this is possible since actually there can be different customer per country (not shown in this simplified schema). But i can't use the customer for the join.

Comment: @TimSchmelter If this is possible, then you'll have to clarify what do you want as a result in this cases, since the duplication will happen. For instance, you'll need to group the `Forecast` table to return the minimum/maximum `ID` when the combination repeats

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Lamak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22966130/full-outer-join-duplicating-rows-using-coalesce/22966511#22966511)** provides the reason for the duplicate rows in the result. Here is one solution:

```
WITH Sales AS
( ... )
, Forecasts AS
( ...)
, Combos AS                             -- get all distinct
(                                       -- model + month + country  
   SELECT Model, Month, Country         -- combinations
   FROM Sales                           -- from Sales
 UNION                                             -- this is UNION DISTINCT
   SELECT Model, Month, Country
   FROM Forecasts                       -- and Forecasts
)
SELECT  ID = COALESCE(s.ID, f.ID), 
        c.Model, 
        c.Month,
        c.Country,
        Amount = COALESCE(s.Amount, f.Amount),
        [Forecast / Sales] = COALESCE(s.[Forecast / Sales], 
                                      f.[Forecast / Sales])
FROM Combos c
  LEFT JOIN Sales s
    ON  s.Model = c.Model
    AND s.Month = c.Month
    AND s.Country = c.Country
  LEFT JOIN Forecasts f 
    ON  s.Model IS NULL           -- join Forecasts only if there is no Sales
    AND f.Model = c.Model
    AND f.Month = c.Month
    AND f.Country = c.Country
ORDER BY ID, Month, Country, Model ;
```

Test at: **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9081b/14)**

Answer (score 8):

The problem with your query isn't the use of `COALESCE`, but simply with the `JOIN`. There are 2 rows in the `Forecast` table that have the same combination of `Model, Month, Country`, rows with `ID` 2 and 3:

```
╔════╦═══════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════╦═══════╗
║ ID ║ Model ║          Month          ║ Country ║ Count ║
╠════╬═══════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════╬═══════╣
║  2 ║ ABC   ║ 2014-02-01 00:00:00.000 ║ Germany ║  1100 ║
║  3 ║ ABC   ║ 2014-02-01 00:00:00.000 ║ Germany ║   900 ║
╚════╩═══════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════╩═══════╝
```

Both of them join with the row `ID` 3 from the `Sales` table:

```
╔════╦═══════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════╦═══════╗
║ ID ║ Model ║          Month          ║ Country ║ Count ║
╠════╬═══════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════╬═══════╣
║  3 ║ ABC   ║ 2014-02-01 00:00:00.000 ║ Germany ║   900 ║
╚════╩═══════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════╩═══════╝
```

And since your query is using `COALESCE(s.ID, fc.ID)`, then you get 2 rows with `ID` 3 in the results

Comment: As commented above, good catch. But what can i do to select only sales-rows? I'm not interested in forecast-data if there is already sales-data for a given model-month-country.

Answer (score 3):

It appears you simply want to return the entire `Sales` set and complement it with entries from `Forecasts` that are not found in `Sales`. For that, I would probably just use UNION ALL [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9081b/15):

```
WITH Sales AS
(
  ...
)
, Forecasts AS
(
  ...
)

SELECT ID, Model, Month, Country, Amount, [Forecast / Sales]
FROM Sales

UNION ALL

SELECT ID, Model, Month, Country, Amount, [Forecast / Sales]
FROM Forecasts
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT Model, Month, Country
  INTERSECT
  SELECT Model, Month, Country
  FROM Sales
);
```

Comment: Oh yeah. Much simpler than mine.

Comment: Are you missing a FROM statement inside the NOT EXISTS (before INTERSECT)?

Comment: @Rubio: I'm not. It's a FROM-less SELECT referencing columns from the outer level. In this case they are `Forecasts` columns. The subquery takes each row of `Forecasts` and intersects its subset with an equivalent projection of `Sales` to see if there are no matches. You could also rewrite it as `NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE Forecasts.Model = Sales.Model AND Forecasts.Month = Sales.Month AND Forecasts.Country = Sales.Country)` with the same effect.

Comment: @Andriy: Hmm, interesting. Does this work in Oracle as well, do you know?

Comment: @Rubio: As far as I know, Oracle doesn't support FROM-less SELECTs, but that doesn't mean the method in general cannot work. I think it should work in Oracle too after you insert `FROM DUAL` immediately before the `INTERSECT`.